# Как транслировать из RTSP потока в HTTP используя VLC плеер в консоли

Tags: vlc

Есть ip-камера, выводящая видео через RTSP, подключаюсь через VLC плеер по URL: **rtsp://192.168.1.52:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?** и смотрю видео на ПК. Нужно открыть данный поток на linux сервере и транслировать его в http. Делал вот так: **vlc -vvv 'rtsp://192.168.1.52:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?' --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ogg,url=192.168.1.41:8081}'** но поток не работает(не транслируется). Помогите разобраться